# Add a selection of default tags to all metas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, per-site-meta, default-tags

Suppose a new user has a question to ask on a new meta site about badges. The meta site is too new to have a badges tag and the user is too new to have enough rep to create tags.

It would be useful if all of the per-site metas had a selection of generic tags from the start. As well as allowing low-rep users to use common meta tags, it would also make it easier for someone wanting to retrieve data on multiple meta sites from the data dump, as tags meaning the same things would have the same names across multiple sites.

Comment: This question exists as a historical list of the original set of default tags. For a continuously updated list of the *current* set of default tags, see this Q&A instead: [What tags exist by default on child metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233898/335251)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good idea!

We started with all the [page 1 tags on meta.so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags), the most mature meta site, and pared out anything meta.so specific.

This left us with:

```
reputation
questions
tags
comments
badges
answers
search
voting
editing
bounty
user-interface
specific-question
accepted-answer
markdown
stackexchange
community-wiki
down-votes
openid
migration
vote-to-close
exact-duplicates
etiquette
notifications
users
closed-questions
hyperlinks
data-dump
asking-questions
delete
recent-activity
new-users
profile-page
flagging
chat
unanswered-questions
retagging
moderation
data-explorer
close-reasons
user-accounts
formatting
interesting-tags
up-votes
meta
statistics
login
rss
favorites
deleted-questions
tagging
votes
tag-synonyms
```

**Any objections to anything here as a default pre-filled tag for meta sites?** We're planning to set these up across *all* child meta sites tonight, and all future child meta sites as well.

Comment: I think `[stackexchange]` isn't necessary, since most of those should come here, but there's no harm leaving it in.

Comment: No `[waffles]`? Boo!

Comment: Are you going to set up the existing tag synonyms for these tags as well?

Comment: The only tag I don't really like is `[delete]` -- I've been thinking about what to do with it here. It should be disambiguated into `[deleted-answers]`, `[deleted-questions]`, etc. I don't think that one should be set up as a default.

Comment: @jon good call, we removed [delete]

Comment: [data-dump] and [data-explorer] are less than necessary on the other sites, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: How about [on-topic-definition]?

Comment: @grace how so? all sites will be dumped under the same cc-wiki terms, and all will be visible in the data explorer..

Comment: Well, my original thought pattern was that [data-explorer] is more often suited to either bug reports/feature requests about the site (which is a topic for this Meta), while [data-dumps] being more of a global thing aren't going to really see a whole lot of questions unique to each site. From my perspective, anything worth discussing about either is best done scoped to the entire network. So I don't see much utility occurring on those sites (especially the less technically inclined sites). That said, there's nothing negative to defaulting them as available.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to edit Jeff's answer, so in addition to the ones he's listed, I would suggest also adding important ones from the second page and on. These are the ones I think are the most important with >= 10 questions on Meta.

I would also recommend transferring over all the related tag synonyms as well.

```
css
accept-rate
user-profiles
spam
moderators
ignored-tags
flair
behavior
email
gravatar
captcha
api
revisions
daily-reputation-limit
linking
deleted-answers
10k-tools
advanced-search
tag-wiki
retag-request (this may already be there)
allowed-topics
answering-questions
images
linked-accounts / associated-accounts (needs merging here)
faq-proposed
comment-replies
reputation-graph
display-names
account-suspension
revisions-list
tag-badges
downvoting
upvoting
faq-update-request
merge-accounts
vote-to-delete
comment-voting
rollbacks
tag-blacklist-request
logout
moderator-nomination
```

Comment: hmm .. [code-formatting]? On sites that don't even have syntax highlighting like cooking.se ? I found that the general all-network value of meta.so tags dropped off precipitously after page 1.. becoming fairly esoteric

Comment: Good point, @Jeff. There's also `[syntax-highlighting]`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation could simply mean looking through the Meta.SE tags database as well as the site-specific meta tag database to index under existing tags.