# What tags exist by default on child metas?

Tags: support, tags, per-site-meta, default-tags

Some tags are automatically created when a new child meta is spawned, including mod-only tags like [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and mandatory tags like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), as well as some ordinary tags like [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty), [users](/questions/tagged/users), and [rss](/questions/tagged/rss).

Using [Japanese.SE's Meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/) as an example: if you look at the [bounty](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty) tag there, you can see that it exists even though there are no questions there, since it asks you if you would like to create a tag wiki for it. On the other hand, the hypothetical [asdfghjkl](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asdfghjkl) tag does not exist at all, and hence does not ask you about creating a tag wiki. (You can also see the "bounty" tag listed on [the Tags page there](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/tags), while "asdfghjkl" is not.)

I would like to know which tags, like [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty), exist by default in the system. It would be particularly nice if this information was available in SEDE or the API, but if not, an answer here would work, too. Knowing this would help me know which tags on meta sites need to have tag wikis added to protect them from the script that deletes single-use tags after 6 months.

I could, I suppose, glean this information by inspecting the tag list on [Hinduism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism?referrer=wzXrCWirCuuJw-d7A6Mm7A2)'s meta right after it launches, but I think it would be good to have this information on Meta.

---

The linked post, [Add a selection of default tags to all metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62655/add-a-selection-of-default-tags-to-all-metas), is not a duplicate; the list in Jeff's answer there is no longer accurate. At minimum, it claims that `delete` is a tag that should be present on all child metas; however, as you can see at Japanese.SE's Meta, [there is no `delete` tag](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of December 2022, the list of default tags on meta sites is:

[accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer)
[answers](/questions/tagged/answers)
[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions)
[badges](/questions/tagged/badges)
[bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) (previously named [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites))<sup>1</sup>
[bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty)
[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
[chat](/questions/tagged/chat)
[closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions)
[close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons)
[comments](/questions/tagged/comments)
[community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads)
[community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki)
[data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump)
[data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)
[deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions)
[design](/questions/tagged/design)
[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
[down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes)
[editing](/questions/tagged/editing)
[etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette)
[exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates)
[faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
[featured](/questions/tagged/featured)
[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
[flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging)
[formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting)
[hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks)
[login](/questions/tagged/login)
[markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown)
[meta](/questions/tagged/meta)
[migration](/questions/tagged/migration)
[moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation)
[new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users)
[notifications](/questions/tagged/notifications)
[openid](/questions/tagged/openid)
[product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery)
[profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page)
[questions](/questions/tagged/questions)
[recent-activity](/questions/tagged/recent-activity)
[reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation)
[retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging)
[rss](/questions/tagged/rss)
[search](/questions/tagged/search)
[site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion)
[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)
[stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange)
[statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics)
[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)
[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
[status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)
[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)
[support](/questions/tagged/support)
[tags](/questions/tagged/tags)
[tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)
[unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions)
[up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes)
[user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts)
[user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface)
[users](/questions/tagged/users)
[vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)
[voting](/questions/tagged/voting)

Notes:

- [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) was removed as a default tag in May 2022, as a result of [this request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310392/335251). (The feature it originally referred to was [renamed to "favorite tags" in 2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/11/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/), and [renamed again to "tag watching" in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/335251).)
- [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) and [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) were removed from the list of default tags on meta sites in December 2022, as a result of [this request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234473/335251). (See the answer there for details on this change.)

---

<sup>1</sup> On all sites created before the feature was renamed, the existing [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) tag was renamed and synonymized to [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks). On sites created after this change, such as [Proof Assistants](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/tags), the [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) tag does not exist at all – but the [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) tag does.