# Please remove some redundant tags from the list of default tags on child metas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, per-site-meta, default-tags

As seen in the answer to [What tags exist by default on child metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233898/224428), there are some redundant tags in the list of defaults. From the following list, please remove one of each pair:

- `tags` or `tagging`
- `votes` or `voting`
- `users` or `user-accounts`

(Also, while we're here, please replace `interesting-tags` with `favorite-tags` - [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) here on Meta.SE is a synonym for [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags), as it should be. Nobody uses "interesting tags" to refer to the favorite-tags filtering mechanism.)

Comment: The last part of your post is a duplicate of this feature-request: [The \[interesting-tags\] tag should not be a default tag on Meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310392/335251) (Also note that [favorite-tags] on MSE has since been renamed to and added as a synonym of [tag-watching], since [that feature was renamed accordingly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/335251).)

Comment: @V2Blast Since you're [tag:status-review]ing tag-related requests lately, here's one: [Can the \[untagged\] tag be blocked on the newer sites too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352726/can-the-untagged-tag-be-blocked-on-the-newer-sites-too)

Comment: A related question that's useful as a reference: [What tags exist by default on child metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233898/335251)

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I started working on this request (and much longer since it was posted), but this request has now been (mostly) completed! **Specifically, [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) and [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) have now been removed from the set of default tags for new meta sites going forward.**

---

In evaluating this request, I asked another CM to take a look at how often these tags were actually being used on meta sites, and whether they'd been synonymized/merged with each other or with other tags. I then analyzed whether they described distinct things based on the name. Here's my assessment, based on those findings:

- **[tags](/questions/tagged/tags) vs. [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging)** – In general, `tagging` is actively used much less than `tags` is. Overall, the `tags` tag is currently in use (i.e. it has been added to a question, and hasn't been synonymized/merged into another tag) on almost all of our sites. Only 2 sites have made it a synonym of `tagging`. Meanwhile, `tagging` seems to be in use on less than half of our sites; there are 36 sites where it has been made a synonym of `tags`. Overall, `tagging` is not obviously differentiated from `tags` just by their names. As such, it made sense to eliminate [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) as a default tag.
- **[votes](/questions/tagged/votes) vs. [voting](/questions/tagged/voting)** – The `voting` tag is actually used significantly more than `votes` is. `votes` is in use on less than half of our meta sites; there are 12 sites where it has been made a synonym of `voting`. However, `voting` is in use on over 75% of our sites, and there are only 3 sites where it has been synonymized into `votes`. Overall, the two tags seem relatively similar in meaning, but [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) seemed to be slightly more useful to keep as a default tag than [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) did – especially since there are already other default tags for [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes), [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes), and [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) specifically.
- **[users](/questions/tagged/users) vs. [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts)** – These 2 tags are relatively similar in frequency of use. `users` is in active use on just over half of our meta sites, and hasn't been synonymized away on any meta site. Similarly, `user-accounts` is used on exactly half of our meta sites (at least at the time we did this analysis), and has been made a synonym of another tag on just one meta site ([the `account` tag on Meta Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/tags/account/synonyms)). Furthermore, they seem to be getting used to refer to different things; understandably, the `user-accounts` tag typically gets used for account-related issues, while `users` tends to get used more broadly on issues relating to specific users, the community as a whole, or really anything relating to specific subsets of users (besides [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users), another default meta tag). As such, I didn't find the evidence compelling enough to get rid of either of these tags; I'm not sure I'd consider them "redundant", at least in the way that the other two pairs of tags are.

As such, I ended up asking the devs that [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) and [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) to remove from the list of default tags on meta sites, which they've now done.

---

**Note that this only affects new meta sites going forward.** It won't change the use of these tags on any of our existing meta sites; it's up to those communities how they want to use these tags (whether that means disambiguating them and using them for different things, or just making one a synonym of the other).

Comment: Won't this change sort of affect existing meta sites as well, in that the old tag names can no longer be used by users without the privilege to create tags if there were no questions previously using them or if all questions using a removed default tag later have the tag edited out or get deleted?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: No, I don't think it would. When we've made changes to the list of default tags in the past, I believe it's only affected tags on existing meta sites when a staff member has separately gone through and synonymized the existing tags away or something. You can see this by looking at the list of tags on older meta sites where the tag remains unused; for instance, [CS50 Meta Stack Exchange](https://cs50.meta.stackexchange.com/) still has `interesting-tags` as a default tag, as well as `tagging` and `votes`.