# Change the default tag [bookmarks] to [saves] on per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, status-review, tags, per-site-meta, default-tags

As we all now know, [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves).

However, the list of [default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233922/377214) on per-site metas (tags that get added to per-site metas whenever a new site is created, and always continue to exist even if there are no questions using them) hasn't been updated to reflect the change. The tag [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) is still a default tag that gets pre-created on them.

Can the [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) tag please be removed as a default tag, and [saves](/questions/tagged/saves) be added in its place? <s>Also, on site metas where the former tag currently has uses, can it please be renamed to the latter and synonymized, as was done with the switch from the old [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) tag to the former?</s>

(Posting this as a separate question rather than as an answer to the announcement since this isn't really a request about the Saves feature itself.)

Comment: Do we really want [bookmarks] merged with [saves]? They're fully separate features; I feel like merging them on any site will probably lead to confusion for new users in the future.

Comment: @zcoop98 I don't follow… There is no longer any feature called bookmarks, right? In what sense do you mean that saves and bookmarks are "fully separate features"?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I mean that, despite Bookmarks not existing anymore, it's still a different feature that worked similarly, but not the same as, the new Saves feature. Specifically with the regards to these tags, Q&A's about Bookmarks may not apply directly to Saves, so suddenly labeling all [bookmark] questions as [saves] questions may end up very confusing to future users.

Comment: @zcoop98 Struck that part out of my post.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with [zcoop98's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382680/change-the-default-tag-bookmarks-to-saves-on-per-site-metas#comment1276408_382680): a merge (/synonymizing) **would lead to a lot of confusion**, both for the end-user and the moderator/staff member.

While the saves feature replaced the bookmarks feature, their functioning and functionality are different. This would cause older questions about bookmarks to become confusing for the use of the saves feature. The tag descriptions need to be rewritten, and any page mentioning their use probably as well.

As for the other issue you point out, however, I completely agree: the default creation of a [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) tag for new sites is now completely unnecessary and should be changed in favour of a default [saves](/questions/tagged/saves) tag.

Comment: That makes sense, and I've struck out the portion of my post asking for the tags to be synonymized or merged. The part asking for the default tags to be changed still stands, though.

Comment: There is still the "*and saves be added in its place?*" question, which has the same intent :)

Comment: The default tags that get created on a site's meta should still be changed. The bookmarks feature no longer exists, so it doesn't make sense to pre-create that tag on brand new site metas. Changing the default tags that get pre-created, by itself, doesn't affect prior questions using the old tag. The question formerly contained another request asking for those prior questions to have their tags changed, which is what I've struck out.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yes, I definitely agree with getting rid of a default 'bookmarks' tag in favour of a 'saves' tag.