# Drop Posts.FavoriteCount from SEDE

Tags: feature-request, status-review, data-explorer, bookmarks

Related: [What happened to FavoriteCount?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383706/295232) - my educated guess is that a `NULL` value indicates a question has *never* been favorited or bookmarked, and 0 that it was. Since the values are so different from what the column name conveys, shouldn't it just be dropped? That would break some old queries of course, but with developer tools it's often better to throw an exception rather than produce deceptive results.

<sub>(Alternative title: `ALTER TABLE Posts DROP COLUMN FavoriteCount` - but I was afraid that would encourage people to post all kinds of SQL questions here ...)</sub>

Comment: Hmm maybe also time to merge [tag:bookmarks] into [tag:saves]? The tag wiki for bookmarks is now just wrong, and the tag itself is misleading, making people think bookmarks still exist.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard either that, or keep them separate (but point out that bookmarks no longer exist and are replaced by saves). The merge from [favorites] to [bookmarks] was a no-brainer because it was the same functionality - this one I'm not sure about that. Sounds like another question :)

Comment: Technically it should be dropped from PostsWithDeleted. `Posts` is only a view over the actual table ...

Comment: Don't they even still have emailhash from the dawn of time when that was public?

Comment: I totally agree, we'll take care of it

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: Related request (though not quite the same, since I assume your suggestion is more about merging the tags on MSE): [Change the default tag \[bookmarks\] to \[saves\] on per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382680/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast yeah, related, not same. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Laurel I'm pretty sure all email hashes have been cleared from SEDE long ago.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars The column still exists on the Users table, but it's blank in every row.

Comment: @rene how do you know? :O

Comment: @Laurel yup, that's why "cleared" and not "removed". ;)

Comment: @Braiam inspection of the schema: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1688218  or [implementation details](https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/f009ab6e0d6b85ae54f6#file-sp_refresh_database-sql-L120)